# Remove part within square brackets for function

Tags: function-construction, symbolic

So I've defined a variable as follows:

```
 q = {{x[t]}, {Φ[t]}}
    V=0.5*x[t]^2*m^2+0.5*Φ[t]^2*I
```

I've had to differentiate with respect to time so:

```
 dq=D[q,t]
```

Giving something like:

```
  q'[t]={{x'[t]}, {Φ'[t]}}
```

I'd now like to use a Function and have found that the following doesn't work:

```
fv=Function[{x, Φ}, D[V, q]][1, pi/8]
```

It seems that x is different to x[t]. Which seems to some regard logical, however it is now impossible to work with the Function.

```
 Function[{x[t],Φ[t]}, D[V, q]][1, pi/8]
```

doesn't work either.
Is there a way to delete the "[t]" part of each variable? Or is there a better way of going about this?

Comment: What do you want to get in the end?

Comment: I'd like the jacobian to be evaluated and then the values x=1 and phi=pi/8 to be substituted in. So in the end a numerical value.

Comment: Can you write a formula that you want in the end?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
q = {x, Φ}  
V = (x^2*m^2 + Φ^2*I)/2

fv = Function[{x, Φ}, Evaluate[Total[Flatten[D[V, {q}]]]]][1, pi/8]
(* m^2 + (I pi)/8 *)
```

gives the desired result, if I understand the question correctly.

**Addendum**

If, as suggested in a comment, it is necessary that `x` and `Φ` have explicit `t` dependence, the following can be used instead.

```
q = {x[t], Φ[t]} 
V = (x[t]^2*m^2 + Φ[t]^2*I)/2
fv = Function[{x, Φ}, Evaluate[Total[Flatten[D[V, {q}]]] /. {x[t] -> x, Φ[t] -> Φ}]]
    [1, pi/8]
```

yielding the same result as before.

Comment: I haven't put the entire script in to the question so it may not make sense as to why I started with q = {x[t], \[Phi][t]}. But in other parts of my script I need to differentiate with respect to t. For example with D[T,D[q,t]] where T is function dependent on on dq/dt.

Comment: @aenes1519  You can use `% /. {x -> x[t], Φ ->Φ[t]}` to add the `t` dependence to the final result.

Comment: Can I also do it the other way around?     %/. {x[t]->x, \[Phi][t]->\[Phi]}    I just tried and it seems to stay the same

Comment: Ignore the last comment, I managed to get it to work by understanding what "%" does. Converting from Matlab to Mathematica for symbolic calculations is proving more difficult than hoped for...